# How do you render a Node's Last Saved date in a Region Footer (ie, inside a Block on every page)?

Tags: blocks, datetime

I'm new to Drupal (8) and have no PHP experience, but I've managed to get this interesting CMS doing just about everything I need by playing with Twigs.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get a Page's "Last Saved" date to render in the footer block though.

In the Node twig I can add this, and it works perfectly:

```
{{ node.changed.value|date("d/m/Y H:i") }}
```

But in the region--footer.html.twig (which is an included block at the base of every page on the site, and where I wish to render this information) all I get back, from every combination I try, is the current date/time of when the page loads in the browser. Actually, i think it is the current server time.

Obviously there's something I just don't get about how Drupal works!

Can anyone offer a newbie some help in language I might understand?

Cheers,
mrEdge

Comment: Depending on which template file you are in, there are different variables available. The `node` variable is typically available in `page.html.twig` and `node.html.twig`, but not in `region.html.twig` or `block.html.twig`. The available variables are documented in the template files of the core theme `stable`

Comment: So I gathered, but what's the workaround @Hudri? How can I globally, for all node types (articles, basic page, front page, taxonomy pages) render a footer that includes the Last Saved date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can add to the *yourtheme.theme* file next thinks;

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  $vars['node'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
}
```

and afterwards in your twig template each region will have available variable `node`.

```
{% if node %}
  {{ node.changed.value|date("d/m/Y H:i") }}
{% endif %}
```

Don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: Hey Alex, Thank you. I've found the .theme file and have inserted the function above. How do I name the "yourtheme_preprocess_region"?

Comment: I had a guess and oh my goodness, it's working! IT IS WORKING!
Thank you Alex!!!!

Comment: @mrEdge this is great!! no problems